# from excel 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I want a dictionary with sales agents as keys and net sales as value. I have no idea why this doesn't work.

```
NetSalesPerAgent_2015 = {}
for agent in pd.read_excel('VerkoopBrouwerij.xlsx',sheet_name='2015')['Agent Name']:
    if agent not in NetSalesPerAgent_2015:
        NetSalesPerAgent_2015[agent] = sum(list(pd.read_excel('VerkoopBrouwerij.xlsx', sheet_name='2015', index_col='Agent Name').loc[agent]['Net Sales']))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check the values in the *'Net Sales'* column of your Excel worksheet for any anomaly.

Then, a simple way to avoid the [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) pitfall, is to multiply input values by 100, 1000 or 10,000 to get rid of the decimals, pass them to the function(s) then divide the output values by that same number.

Use pandas `read_excel()` to read the Excel worksheet into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('VerkoopBrouwerij.xlsx', sheet_name='2015')
```

Use `mul()` to multiply *'Net Sales'* values to get rid of the decimals (e.g. 10,000 for 4 decimals digits):

```
df['Net Sales'] = df['Net Sales'].mul(10000)
```

Use `groupby()` and `sum()` to create a series of the total *'Net Sales'* of each *'Agent Name'*:

```
ser = df.groupby('Agent Name')['Net Sales'].sum()
```

Use `div()` to divide the series and get the decimals back:

```
ser = ser.div(10000)
```

Use `to_dict()` to convert the series to a dictionary:

```
NetSalesPerAgent_2015 = ser.to_dict()
```

Test worksheet used:

*Agent Name | Net Sales
 A | 10.5005
 B | 20.6006
 C |
30.7007
 D | 40.8008
 D | 10.5005
 B | 20.6006
 A | 30.7007
 C | 40.8008*

Result:

```
{'A': 41.2012, 'B': 41.2012, 'C': 71.5015, 'D': 51.3013}
```